# svnサーバーからのチェックアウトが途中で止まってしまう。

Tags: apache, svn

現在svnサーバーを構築しているものです。
svnサーバーはhttp経由でリポジトリにアクセスできるように設定しました。(modules/mod_dav_svn.soなどを入れてます。)

コミット、チェックアウト、アップデート問題なくできるのですが、大きめのリポジトリをチェックアウトしようとすると途中まではローカルに落ちてくるのですが、途中で止まってしまい以下のエラーが出て終了してしまいます。

```
svn: E120108: Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

しかし、httpdプロセスは死んでおらず、エラーログにも特に出力されているものはありませんでした。
メモリ不足の問題も特にありません。
通信回線は社内の回線を使っているので、通信が細いとかの問題は無さそうです。
httpdのタイムアウト設定などを疑ってみましたが、60秒設定されているので、十分な時間設定で特に問題は無さそうです。

この問題に対して他にどのようにアプローチしていけばよろしいでしょうか。
宜しくお願い致します。

```
svn: version 1.9.7
httpd: Apache/2.2.34
```

Comment: KeepAlive はOnでしょうか？Offの場合、MaxClientsの上限に達して それ以上のリクエストが遮断される場合があります。

Comment: keepaliveはoffになっていました。ですが、MaxClientsは256でリクエストはひとまず自分だけなので、それによるリクエスト遮断ではなさそうです。

ちょっとわかったことがありまして、メモリ不足じゃないと記載したのですが、切断される直前のメモリ使用量をみたら、ほぼMAXまで使用していることがわかりました。
なので、メモリ不足が原因のようです。
httpdがメモリを大量に食っているようでして、チェックアウトが進むにつれて使用メモリ量が増え続けるのですが、巨大なリポジトリのチェックアウトの際はいつもhttpdはメモリ使用量が増え続ける動きをするのでしょうか？
チェックアウトが無事に終わったとしても使用済みメモリを解放するために再起動をかけないと次のチェックアウトができないのですが、どう考えても普通の動き方じゃないなと思いました。

Comment: なるほど、メモリ不足の際、起動している httpd のプロセスの数はいくつありますか？ httpdがpreforkの設定になってる場合、１セッション=１プロセスになるので、keepalive off だと、ユーザは1名でも、SVNによってセッションが多数はられてと httpd プロセスがどんどん増えていく ということがあります。keepalive on にすると セッションが再利用されるので、プロセスが増えなくなるので、一度試してみていただけますか？

Comment: もう使っていたインスタンスは潰してしまったので、うる覚えですがhttpdプロセス自体は初期段階から6,7個あったと思います。
その後topで監視していましたがプロセス自体が大量に増えてったということはなさそうでした。
ただ、不審だったのがhttpdプロセスは立ち上げたときから仮想メモリがすべてのhttpdプロセスで200M前後取られていたのです。
そして、この後原因がわかりまして、どうやらapache2.2のmod_deflateモジュールによる不具合だと判明しました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645733/huge-svn-checkout-made-apache-dav-svn-consume-all-memory-on-server-any-tips

http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3084
なので、apache2.4を入れ直したところ、チェックアウト中でもメモリが一定までは増加しますが、ちゃんと途中で解放されているようで、青天井に増え続けることはなくなりました。

Comment: 解決したようで何よりです。もしよければ、解決した内容を、ご自身で「回答」して、解決マークをつけてもらえますか？ そうすると この質問のステータスが 解決済みになります。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

こちらapache2.2のmod_deflateモジュールが原因のようでした。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645733/huge-svn-checkout-made-apache-dav-svn-consume-all-memory-on-server-any-tips

apache2.4にすることで一旦本問題に関しては解決することができました。